# Подскажите, как максимально коротко записать программу на Питоне

Tags: python

```
for i in a:
    if i == 'S' or i == 'M' or i == 'E':
        print(a.index(i) + 1)
        break
```

Answer (score 4):

```
print([i for i, c in enumerate(a) if c in 'SME'][0] + 1)
```

Только зачем эта экономия строк в ущерб читаемости? У тебя самый простой, понятный и более эффективный вариант. Хотя этот вариант позволяет найти все вхождения

Comment: С эффективностью можно поспорить. Есть решения в 300 раз быстрее на длинных строках.

Answer (score 3):

Просто поиск. Достаточно ясно выражает идею - что мы делаем:

```
for i, v in enumerate(a, start=1):
    if v in 'SME':
        print(i)
        break
```

Регулярное выражение. Если вы знакомы с регулярными выражениями - идея кода будет ясна:

```
import re


m = re.search('[SME]', a)
if m:
    print(m.end())
```

Поиск отдельных символов. Код сложный и непонятный. Он тут из-за скорости:

```
i = len(a)
for c in 'SME':
    j = a.find(c, 0, i)
    if j != -1:
        i = j
if i != len(a):
    print(i + 1)
```

Comment: можно в enumerate передать единицу

Comment: @Danis, спасибо!

Comment: с RegEx пожалуй самое короткое и понятное решение, если автору нужна 1 строка, то можно так: print(re.search('[SME]', ''.join(a)).start() + 1)

Comment: Для решения с re не хватает строки импорта

Comment: @АлексейР, спасибо!

Comment: @VitaliyZlobin, вы, видимо предполагаете что `a` - список символов (нужен `join`). Я предполагаю что `a` - строка (не нужен `join`). Ваш вариант не обрабатывает случай отсутствия символа в строке.

Comment: @АлексейР да, если строка, то ещё проще: print(re.search('[SME]', 'MyString').start() + 1)

Answer (score 2):

Практически не пишу на питоне, наверное поэтому для меня  (после просмотра ответов тут и 5 минут в гугле для организации цикла по индексам строки) самый очевидный код для этой задачи оказался вот таким:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   if a[i] in 'SME':
       print(i + 1)
       break
```

Что удивительно, он содержит примерно столько же букв, что и все остальные примеры...

Также надеюсь, что генератор `range` и операция поиска `in` реализованы в языке достаточно эффективно.

Comment: `range` и `in` реализованы, по сути, на `c`, так что они работают достаточно эффективно

Answer (score 1):

```
i = next((i+1 for i,x in enumerate(a) if x in "SME"), None)
if i: print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если выражение что-то найдет, выведет порядковый номер символа, если нет - 0.
Метод `find()` в подвыражениях возвращает индекс символа, если найдет, или -1 если не найдет. Поэтому прибавляем единицу к каждому результату поиска. Т.е. если не нашел, то -1+1 = 0 (или ложь), тогда переходим к вычислению следующего подвыражения через `or`. Если же нашел, то подвыражение возвращает число > 0, на этом вычисление заканчивается, а результат выводится.

```
a = 'AASABBBMCCCEDDD'
print((a.find('S') + 1) or (a.find('M') + 1) or (a.find('E') + 1))
```

```
3
```

Comment: Этот способ не всегда находит первое вхождение.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = min((a.index(x) + 1 for x in "SME" if x in a), default=None)
if i: print(i)
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, у автора вопроса индексация с 1. Я просто добавить забыл - исправил.

Answer (score 0):

#### Очередная задача на сокращение кода?

Как уже говорили [ранее](/a/1507825/418625), **коротко ≠ понятно** и читаемо. Это можно убедится по ответам, которые уже предложили ранее.

Моё решение в одну строку с минимальным числом символов. Идея с `next` и `enumerate` уже использовалась [ранее](/a/1508146/418625), также используется [walrus оператор](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/555924/).

```py
if x:=next((i+1 for i,c in enumerate(a)if c in"SME"),0):print(x)
```

###### Краткое объяснение фокусов.

Мы проходимся в цикле и, если выполняется условие с символами, возвращается `index+1`, что является `True`. Иначе мы возвращаем 0, `False`.

Comment: Начиная с Python3.12 код `1for` будет выдавать `SyntaxWarning`, а дальше - `SyntaxError`.